# Linux CentOS 7, how to set Python2.7 as default Python version?

Tags: python, linux, centos, centos7

I'm using a laptop running Linux CentOS 7.
I installed Python2.7, and then I installed Anaconda, which installed Python3.5.2

I want my system to use Python2.7 as default, but if I type `python` from my terminal, it launches Python3.5.2 from Anaconda:

```
[davide@opennet-33-58 ~]$ python
Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:53:06) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

I tried to remove Python3 but it's still there...

**How can I set Python2.7 as default Python version on my machine?**

Thanks

Comment: This looks like CentOS6 and not CentOS7 since the GCC is 4.4.7. Can you confirm?

Comment: @MattSchuchard It's CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way: just add an alias into your /home/.bashrc like:

```
alias python="/usr/bin/python3.5"
```

(I suppose CentOS have similar structure as Linux Mint)

But you probably should just use virtual env, [here's](http://python-guide-pt-br.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs) a link to get you started. Solving issues like this one is the primary purpose of a virtual env.

Comment: I already tried but did not work for scripts. Something like `python script.py` would always use python3.5

Answer (score 1):

For RHE/Centos.
You will need to enable the correct repo if you don't have them.(For my case was the following)

```
subscription-manager repos --enable=rhel-6-server-optional-rpms

subscription-manager repos --enable=rhel-server-rhscl-6-rpms
```

Then you install

```
yum install scl-utils
yum install centos-release-scl-rh  (only for Centos)
yum install python27  (or any version you need to install)
```

Now the new python is installed,you have to enable it as default

```
scl enable python27 bash (with this command will be default until you logout,is good to test the changes)
```

To keep the changes
you should create a script under /etc/profile.d/

```
#!/bin/bash
source scl_source enable python27
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you would like to get familiar with *alternatives*

*alternatives* creates, removes, maintains and displays information about the symbolic links comprising the alternatives system. The alternatives system is a reimplementation of the Debian alternatives system.

[Check out this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48757130/7120073) where i quickly go over the basic commands to achieve what you are requesting and also have a look at [*alternatives* manpages](https://linux.die.net/man/8/alternatives)

Answer (score -1):

Links python2.7 to python

```
sudo ln -fs /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python
```

this is my example:

```
$ python
Python 3.5.2 (default, Sep 14 2017, 22:51:06) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 

$ ls -l /usr/bin/python3.5
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4456240 Sep 18  2017 /usr/bin/python3.5
$ ls -l /usr/bin/python
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 Dec  3 13:52 /usr/bin/python -> /usr/bin/python3.5
$ 
$ sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python
$ ls -l /usr/bin/python
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 Dec  3 13:52 /usr/bin/python -> /usr/bin/python2.7
$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried but it says: `ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/usr/bin/python’: File exists`

Comment: sudo rm /usr/bin/python is VERY VERY dangerous for your system!

Answer (score -1):

If you want to set python2.7 as default Python for all the users add this line to /etc/profile.d/python_alias.sh (create the file if it does not exist):

```
alias python="/usr/bin/python2.7"
```

if you want to set python2.7 as default Python only for some users change the line above to:

```
case "$(whoami)" in
    <USER1>|<USER2>)
        alias python="/usr/bin/python2.7"
        ;;
```

Comment: Thanks but it does not work for scripts like `python script.py`